# Deriving consistency feature for a student using a study app over the days

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-extraction, feature-scaling, feature-construction

I want to build a recommendation engine for the revision app.

Basic Idea

After each module we will ask student questions and based on the correctness of their answers we will decide after how many days students should be revised that topic and again tested to have the maximum memory with the minimised cost function for effort on revision.

One of the features here is Consistency.

I am thinking of using the run over the no of days to derive at the consistency. Consistency should be comparable among the students.

For e.g.

| Day | Run - Studied |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 - Studied |
| 2 | 2 - Studied |
| 3 | 3 - Studied |
| 4 | 0 - Not Studied |
| 5 | 1 - Studied |
| 6 | 2 - Studied |
| 7 | 0 - Not Studied |
| 8 | 1 - Studied |
| 9 | 0 - Not Studied |

I am not sure how i can statistically derive consistency from here. Or shall I think of some else feature to engineer this feature.